# How to generate public key from private key in Rust?

Tags: ecdsa, rust, secp256k1

How to generate Ethereum public key from private key in Rust?

I found [rust-secp256k1](https://github.com/paritytech/rust-secp256k1) and it seems to be what I need, but there is no documentation at all, which makes this crate for me, Rust newbie, nightmare.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: This question was answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53713063/7310095).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also not a Rust programmer, so someone will probably have a better answer, but have a look in Parity's [`keypair.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/ethkey/src/keypair.rs), which itself uses `rust-secp256k1`.

Of interest is probably the [`KeyPair`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/ethkey/src/keypair.rs#L45) implementation.

```
impl KeyPair {
    /// Create a pair from secret key
    pub fn from_secret(secret: Secret) -> Result<KeyPair, Error> {
        let context = &SECP256K1;
        let s: key::SecretKey = key::SecretKey::from_slice(context, &secret[..])?;
        let pub_key = key::PublicKey::from_secret_key(context, &s)?;
        let serialized = pub_key.serialize_vec(context, false);

        let mut public = Public::default();
        public.copy_from_slice(&serialized[1..65]);

        let keypair = KeyPair {
            secret: secret,
            public: public,
        };

        Ok(keypair)
    }
...
```

Comment: Have been playing with these lines, without success yet :)

Comment: Good luck - let us know if you get it working :-)